# Combining "Set" and "If" to count not hidden red cells

Tags: excel, vba

Every cell that has a value of 0, that row will be hidden. And any value that is outside the minimum and maximum values ​​will be red.

```vb
Set mr = Sheets("COA").Range("i11:i34")
For Each cell In mr
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        MsgBox
```

That code isn't as expected because the red hidden cells are also counted.

I asked before, and people answered

```vb
Set rng = Range("Your range").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

but, how if I have two conditions? How do I combine set and if?

condition A = if the active cell is red, return to the userform and
condition B = if the active cell isn't red, unload userform

```vb
Set Rng = Range("i11:i34").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
    MsgBox "bla bla bla", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
    
    'Show Excel and resize the UserForm2
    Application.Visible = True
    Me.Height = 405
    Me.Width = 730.5
End If
    
If ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 0 Then
    MsgBox "bla bla bla", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
End If
```

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"? What happens? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime error? On which line? Or does the code run but doesn't do what you expect? What do you expect anyhow? Have you used the debugger to find out? Btw: You are assigning something to `Rng` but don't use it.

Comment: Please, try: `Set rng = Range("Your range").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` followed by `Dim cel As Range` `For Each cel In mr.cells` `If cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then` `'do something` `Next cel`. I used `cel` variable, not `cell`, which has already a meaning for VBA...

Comment: Thank you again! Now your question is clear, and I see you already received an answer too. Now, a final request, as these comments are not relevant and needed anymore, I will delete my comments and ask you to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying?

Remember, it is always better to write clear concise codes. Also best to fully qualify your objects. One more thing. When working with `SpecialCells` always sandwich them between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` as I have shown below else you may get an error.

BTW I have not used `If-Then-Else`. I have used `Select Case`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim VisibleCells As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("I11:I34")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VisibleCells = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not VisibleCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each aCell In VisibleCells
            Select Case aCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                Case vbRed
                    MsgBox "Blah1", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
                    'Show Excel and resize the UserForm2
                    'Application.Visible = True
                    'Me.Height = 405
                    'Me.Width = 730.5
                Case 0
                    MsgBox "Blah2", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
                '~~> For no color use the below
                'Case 16777215
                    'MsgBox "Blah3", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
            End Select
        Next aCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is work in my excel. I hope you always healthy

Comment: Sorry, i want to ask again. So in the sheet there is a table that contains the values. if the value is out of specification then the cell is red. If cell A is red but cell B is not red, it still shows a message that it is "out of spec". I use your code but the cells that are not red are still counted, even though there are red cells

Comment: Are the cells conditionally formatted?

Comment: yes, the cells use conditionally formating

Comment: You can't use `.Interior.Color` for conditionally formatted cells to check for the interior color. If you search stackoverflow there are many posts which explain how to do that.